# Facebook-C#-SDK: What is the DesktopSession equivalent (3.0.x) in the Graph API version (5.0.x)?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

3.0.1 had the very handy Facebook.Session.DesktopSession class, which is great for a non-Web app trying to get authenticated/authorized. Is there an equivalent in the 5.0.x Graph API version? I sure don't want to have to build my own WPF or WinForms app for this. I am working on PowerShell-izing the 5.0.x API...

Also wondering how difficult it would be to get a .NET 2.0-compatible version of the 5.0.x Graph API. It is possible to get PowerShell running against .NET 3.5/4.0, but it isn't default, and it introduces compatibility issues with other modules.

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent for DesktopSession in v5 graph api version. The only way to make facebook request is to use the access token.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token")
```

Here is a detailed blog post on authentication and authorization process. http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

We don't plan to support .net 2.0 as we use certain Linq extension methods inside the SDK.